# Сделать элемент активным при медиа запросе

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Есть следующее :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
  #media_wrapper{
   height:100%;////?????
   display: inline-block;
  }
}
.media_container{
  height: 100%;
  position: relative
}
#media_wrapper{
 height:100%;
 display: none;
}
```

Как вы видите элемент не активен при больших экранах, но я не знаю как правильно прописать в запросе атрибут `display` на отображение на малом экране, перепробовав например : `block` или `inline-block`, результат один - ничего не отображается. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.media_container{
  height: 100%;
  position: relative
}
#media_wrapper{
 height:100%;
 display: none;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
  #media_wrapper{
   height:100%;
   display: block;
  }
}
```

Медиа запрос всегда нужно добавлять внизу